# How to configure vs2012 to only keep the latest test result?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

By default it appears Visual Studio is keeping all the unit test results. This builds up over the time: 7GB over about 2 months of work. Is there a configuration I can tweak to have it only keep the last few (say 3) or last 24 hours' worth of test results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools->Options->Test Tools and configure the "Limit number of Test Results" to 3

Comment: I thought there is no configuration for that. +1

Comment: Hmm, now that it seems that the 'Test Tools' tab in my VS2012 Tools Options is missing. Anyway to bring it back short of re-install everything?

Comment: Odd. Which version of VS are you using? I would try devenv /resetuserdata before doing a repair